# How to properly implement d3 svg click with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I'm creating a d3 map by integrating it with React. Basically, I have a `mapchart` component that creates the map following this approach: http://bl.ocks.org/herrstucki/9238916

I want to make my map zoomable by clicking a particular state/canton/district etc like shown here https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590

So, basically I have to add a event handler for `click` on the svg as shown in the 2nd map that calls the `clicked()` function.

I tried to implement the `clicked` function inside the React component as so:

```
 return React.DOM.svg({width: this.props.width, height: this.props.height},
  React.DOM.g({
    width: this.props.width,
    height: this.props.height,
  },
    React.DOM.path({
      className: 'states',
      d: path(states),
      onClick: this.clicked, // ** added click event here **
    }),
    React.DOM.path({
      className: 'state-borders',
      d: path(stateBorders),
    })
  ),
);
```

However, when implementing the clicked function I ran into a problem.

```
  clicked() {
    var states = select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)).select('path.states');
    var d = states.attr('d');   // ** not what i thought it would be **

    var group = select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)).select('g');

    var path = geoPath();
    var x, y, k;
    var centered;

    if (d && centered !== d) {
      var centroid = path.centroid(d);
      console.log(centroid)
      x = centroid[0];
      y = centroid[1];
      k = 4;
      centered = d;
    } else {
      x = this.props.width / 2;
      y = this.props.height / 2;
      k = 1;
      centered = null;
    }

    group.selectAll("path")
         .classed("active", centered && function(d) { return d === centered; });

    group.transition()
         .duration(750)
         .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.props.width / 2 + "," + this.props.height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
         .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
  }
```

The `path.centroid(d)` is not working since the value of `d` doesn't seem to be the right format and I'm not sure how the clicked state will be highlighted. In the normal d3 version the `d` of the correct state and dataformat seems to be implicitly passed to the function. How to I get my React component function to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

First, as you discovered, `states.attr('d')` is returning the **d attribute** of the path, i.e. the `...` in `<path d="..." />`. The `d` in the map example is supposed to be the **datum** of the state that was clicked, i.e. the data that is bound to the clicked DOM element, which is in turn an entry from the TopoJSON file you loaded.

Since you're creating DOM nodes using React, rather than d3, there is no data bound to the DOM elements. It means that you have to manage the association between the clicked DOM node and the related datum. You could do this:

```
React.DOM.path({
  className: 'states',
  d: path(states),
  onClick: this.clicked.bind(this, states), // ** added click event here **
})
```

That way, `states` will be passed to `clicked()` as its first param:

```
function clicked(d) {
  // now you have d!
}
```

However, that approach alone doesn't let you know which actual state was clicked, because you're drawing ALL the states into a single `<path>`. The d3 example creates a path per state, so that when a path is clicked, its datum is that state's data object. To do it equivalently in React, you have to loop and create multiple paths. It's hard for me to provide correct code, because I don't know the contents of `states`. But assuming `states` is an array of TopoJSON features, more or less the following should work (switching to JSX here):

```
<svg width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height}>  
  <g>{
    states.map(function (state, i) {
      return (<path
        className='states'
        key={'state_' + i}
        d={path(state)}
        onClick={this.clicked.bind(this, state)}
      </path>)
    })
  }</g>
</svg>
```